# pandas groupby aggregation having same value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm organizing an excel file with pandas, and this line is basically the important stuff. df is the data I'm reading, and out is the output.

```
keep_the_same = ["foo", "bar"]
ones_to_sort = ["somethingelse", "something"]
out = df.groupby(keep_the_same)[ones_to_sort].agg("，".join).reset_index()
```

In some cells, there are same data due to the way the original data was terribly made, are there any simple ways to *merge* them I'm not aware of?
[image: example of repeating same item]

[image: another example]

[image: another just to be sure]

Comment: Can you please provide some non-screenshot expected results?

Comment: so what I'm trying to get is to merge all those same datas into just one element, I don't really need all those same element, I just want to merge all the same values into one

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to test without example data, but aggregating with a custom function to join unique values should work:

```
out = (df.groupby(keep_the_same)[ones_to_sort]
         .agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique().tolist()))
         .reset_index())
```